# Apple Numbers sum if is date is in Month

Tags: sum, apple-numbers

In Apple numbers I tried to sum cells if the date is in a specific month.
So I have a column **A** with a date and column B has a price.

| Date | Price |
| --- | --- |
| 29-07-2021 | 12,50 |
| 16-06-2021 | 15,00 |

I use the function **sum.if** and the function **month** that returns the number of the month.
My formule look like this
**som.if(month(Date));7;Price);**

But this generates an error numbers can only check one date and not for each row for counting.

Is there anybody who can help me with this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Use `SUMPRODUCT()` instead. I am using US-EN version of excel. So, decimal separator and formula definition may differ.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B2:B3)*(MONTH(A2:A3)=7))
```

If you want to use `SUNIFS()` then can try-

```
=SUMIFS(B2:B3,A2:A3,">="&DATE(2021,7,1),A2:A3,"<="&DATE(2021,7,31))
```

If you have `Excel-365` then can use `FILTER()` function like-

```
=SUM(FILTER(B2:B3,MONTH(A2:A3)=7))
```

[image]